# Generating multiple column to sort the data out in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a database including names, codes and rooms as follows:

```html
Name1 Code1 R1
A A 12 1
A B 13 2
A C 15 5
A B 8 4
A C 13 2
A D 17 1
A B 16 7
```

I want to generate columns for  the repeated names like this:

```html
Name1 Code1 R1 Name2 Code2  R2 Name3 Cod3 R3
A A 12 1      
A B 13 2      
A C 15 5      
A B 8 4 A B 8 4   
A C 13 2 A C 13 2   
A D 17 1      
A B 16 7    A B 16 7
```

I have googled to find a solution, but I could not find or may be I have missed something. Would it be possible for you to help me. Some names (Name1) has been repeated 5 times and i did not add it.So I I have Name2 Code2 R2; Name3, Code3, R3...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = F, header = T,  text = "
Name1a Name1b   Code1   R1
1 A A   12  1
2 A B   13  2
3 A C   15  5
4 A B   8   4
5 A C   13  2
6 A D   17  1
7 A B   16  7") %>%
  tidyr::unite(Name1, Name1a, Name1b)
```

Edit: Orig answer was in packed format, but OP would like the first set of columns repeated for all lines, and 2nd and third appearances showing up in the row they originally appeared in.

Here's an approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
# Keep track of original rows, label repeats, and make it long format
df_order <- df %>% 
  mutate(orig_row = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Name1) %>% mutate(repeat_no = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  gather(col_type, value, Code1:R1)

# Make one copy of all the rows to keep in first column
df_ones <- df_order %>%
  mutate(repeat_no = 1) %>%
  unite(col_rpt, repeat_no, col_type)

# Get the repeated rows to add on
df_repeats <- df_order %>%
  filter(repeat_no > 1) %>%
  unite(col_rpt, repeat_no, col_type)

# Combine the two and spread out
output <- df_ones %>%
  bind_rows(df_repeats) %>%
  spread(col_rpt, value) %>%
  arrange(orig_row) %>%
  select(-orig_row)
```

Output:

```
> output
# A tibble: 7 x 7
  Name1 `1_Code1` `1_R1` `2_Code1` `2_R1` `3_Code1` `3_R1`
  <chr>     <int>  <int>     <int>  <int>     <int>  <int>
1 A_A          12      1        NA     NA        NA     NA
2 A_B          13      2        NA     NA        NA     NA
3 A_C          15      5        NA     NA        NA     NA
4 A_B           8      4         8      4        NA     NA
5 A_C          13      2        13      2        NA     NA
6 A_D          17      1        NA     NA        NA     NA
7 A_B          16      7        NA     NA        16      7
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon, but it does not reflect the outcome